# Proving an energy estimate of $2 \delta \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u_t\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|b\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|u_t\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, functional-inequalities

I want to prove that
$$2 \delta \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u_t\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|b\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u_t\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \frac{1+2\sqrt{\delta}}{2}(\|u_t\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|u_x\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\delta\|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)})+\frac{1}{2}\|b\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
and this is what I did for all $\epsilon>0$,
$$ 2\delta \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u_t\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\!+\|b\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u_t\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\!\leq \delta(\epsilon\|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\|u_t\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)})+\frac{1}{2}\|b\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
but I could not get to the inequality. I did not find an adequate $\epsilon>0$, in order to have the first inequality.

Comment: Not sure how $u_x$ comes out on the RHS. Are you also using the PDE?

Comment: Well it’s easy to add the $u_x$ norm because it’s a positive quantity

Comment: Just choose $\epsilon = \sqrt{\delta}$.

Comment: @ArcticChar well i tried and I can't get $\frac{1+2\sqrt{\delta}}{2}$